# PWA on Iphone with camera always start in full screen. Need to reduce to see html button

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, vue.js, camera

I'm currently trying to make a pwa app using vue framework for all phone (Android & Apple) that use camera.

Using mediaDevices, I can enable the camera and see video stream on the phone. This work well on Android, and I can add a button above the video in order to let user click on it to capture a photo.

The problem occurs on Iphone. When camera is switch on, it seems that the video is displayed in full screen, above all other widget. In that case, I could not see anymore the button on the top layer.
If I use the 2 fingers to reduce the video on the screen, I can then see the button above the video, and then click to save picture.

Is there something I missed regarding Iphone ??
It seems that by default, when camera is start, this will be displayed above all other windows.

When I reduce the size, I can see the 2 arrows in upper left that let user expand the video in full screen. This is the Iphone native button...
Is there an option of Iphone to let user start in full screen or not ?

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VIDEO tag - try to add playsinline attribute to it (empty). Worked in my case.

Comment: Could you share a code sample ?

Comment: <video src="someSrc" autoplay playsinline ></video>